# How to properly reuse same behavior for an adapter item in multiple fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter

I have a same adapter item that shows up in multiple fragments. The item has the same actions and behavior in all fragments. Currently I handle the actions in all fragments separately.

I would like to hear some suggestions on how to properly and where to handle these item actions so as to reuse also the behavior of the item.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If each item behavior is same like if you click from any fragment on any item and it goes to same activity/fragment then you can put a single item click listener inside your adapter class and add adapter to your all fragment.it will handle single click listener for all fragment other wise you can make a single interface to handle all fragment with different type behavior when an item is clicked.